# NodeJS passport dosen't redirect after local-authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a problem with my NodeJS application. I use Passport for authentication, and it seems to work as the protected routes can't be reached without an authenticated session. The only problem is that the /login route, dosen't redirect after sussessfull login. I have to do it manually.
I read some posts about it, and what people suggests is that it might be due to this line, not present in the code, but I have that already:

```
})(req, res, next);
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {   req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();   req.assert('password', 'Password cannot be blank').notEmpty();   req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false });

  const errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/login');   }

  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { 
      console.log("Error");
      return next(err); 
    }
    if (!user) {
      console.log("Error again");
      req.flash('errors', info);
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      console.log("logged in");
      if (err) { 
        console.log("Woops not: "+err);
        return next(err); 
      }
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! You are logged in.' });
      res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
    });   })(req, res, next); };
```

And my passport config:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
  console.log("Email fra Passport: "+email);
  console.log("Password fra Passport: "+password);
  let pwdhash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);

    const client = pool.connect();

pool.connect((err, client, release) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack)
    }
    client.query('SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE "email"=$1',[email], (err, result) => {
      release()
      if (err) {
        return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
      }
      if(result.rows[0] == null){
        console.log("Oops. Incorrect login details");
        //req.flash('danger', "Oops. Incorrect login details.");
        return done(null, false);
      }
      else{
        bcrypt.compare(password, result.rows[0].password, function(err, check) {
        console.log(pwdhash);
        console.log(result.rows[0].password);
        if (err){
          console.log('Error while checking password: '+err);
          return done(null, false, { msg: 'Password did not match.' });
        }
        else if (check){
          console.log("All good");
          return done(null, [{email: result.rows[0].email, firstName: result.rows[0].firstName}]);
        }
        else{
          console.log("Invalid email or password: "+check);
          return done(null, false, { msg: 'Invalid email or password.' });
        }
        });
      }
      console.log(result)
    })
  })
}));
```

Ay ideas why my code wont do the redirect to:

```
res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
```

UPDATE:

Updated with routes to static content and the user routes from app.js:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
//Handling specific pathts due to the changes from local modules to node_modules, we need this:
app.use('/webfonts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public/css/fonts/@fortawesome', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public/css/fonts/flaticon', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/flaticon/font'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public/flaticon2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/flaticon2'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public/css/fonts/flaticon2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/flaticon2/font'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));
app.use('/public/css/fonts/line-awesome', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css/line-awesome/fonts'), { maxAge: 31557600000 }));

/**
 * Primary app routes.
 */
app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/dashboard', dashboardController.index);
app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
app.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
app.get('/logout', userController.logout);
app.get('/forgot', userController.getForgot);
app.post('/forgot', userController.postForgot);
app.get('/reset/:token', userController.getReset);
app.post('/reset/:token', userController.postReset);
app.get('/signup', userController.getSignup);
app.post('/signup', userController.postSignup);
app.get('/contact', contactController.getContact);
app.post('/contact', contactController.postContact);
app.get('/account', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getAccount);
app.post('/account/profile', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postUpdateProfile);
app.post('/account/password', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postUpdatePassword);
app.post('/account/delete', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.postDeleteAccount);
app.get('/account/unlink/:provider', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getOauthUnlink);
```

Comment: It depends on how your app.js/server.js is written to serve the static assets or the api invoking.

Comment: Just updated my question with some of the code from app.js, is this what you where asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Searched around on stackoverflow and found out that it was do to an ajax post. So the success from the backend didn't handle the redirect (as it shouldn't). I've updated the success: to make the redirect instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code yet. But I know, In passport have support redirect after login by authenicate passport middleware. You can try:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

If you want using flash to send message. You can add atribute after `failureRedirect`: `failureFlash: true`